# Validar que el usuario introduzca un decimal válido

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de validar un campo para que el usuario no ponga un punto en vez de un numero.

```
private void Calcular() {
        String validar = EditText1.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!validar.isEmpty()){
            if(!validar.matches(".")){
                double x = Double.parseDouble((EditText1.getText().toString().trim()));
                if(x > 0){
            //codigo
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserta un numero mayor a cero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserta un numero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserta un numero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

El primer if es para validar que esta vació, si funciona.
El segundo if es para validar que el usuario no ponga un punto en vez de un numero y evitar que la aplicación crashee (con este tengo el problema)

y el tercer if es para validar que sea mayor a cero, si funciona.

Pero con el punto tengo problemas, tambien el primer valor no lo reconoce.

Comment: Te recomiendo que tu String no se llame "validar" porque no valida nada, alli solo tienes el texto introducido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [String#matches(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) espera como parámetro una expresión regular y retorna `true` si la cadena sobre la que se invoca dicho método coincide con dicha expresión.

La expresión regular que estás utilizando (`"."`) validaría que la cadena se componga solo de un caracter, sea cual sea este. Te recomiendo que estudies un poco el tema de las expresiones regulares para que aprendas como utilizarlas.

Para solucionar tu problema te recomiendo que utilices el método [String#contains​(CharSequence)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) que te permitirá saber si la cadena `validar` contiene un punto.

```
validar.contains("."); // devuelve true si validar contiene un punto
```

**Editado por cambio en la pregunta**

Si por otro lado lo que necesitas es validar que el texto contenido en `validar` tenga un formato válido de número decimal si te podría ayudar el método `String#matches(String)` utilizando esta expresión regular:

```
validar.matches("^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}$")
```

Pruebas realizadas:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = "^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}$";

    System.out.println("".matches(regex));// false
    System.out.println(".".matches(regex));// false
    System.out.println(".5".matches(regex));// false
    System.out.println("1.".matches(regex));// false
    System.out.println("1.0".matches(regex));// true
    System.out.println("1".matches(regex));// true
    System.out.println("16466.0464546".matches(regex));// true
    System.out.println("16646".matches(regex));// true
    System.out.println("0".matches(regex));// true
}
```

Con dicha expresión puedes validar todo lo que necesitas menos que el número sea mayor que 0. Tu código debería ser algo así:

```
private void Calcular() {
    String validar = EditText1.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!validar.matches("^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,1}$")){
        double x = Double.parseDouble((EditText1.getText().toString().trim()));
        if(x > 0){
            //codigo
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserta un numero mayor a cero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserta un numero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo había intentando con contains, pero no me acepta valores double como 3.5, 6.8, 23.75. Solo valores enteros. El teclado que pone android studio contiene 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 0, y el punto

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta está mal enfocada. ¿Qué es lo que necesitas lograr realmente?

Comment: Es un multiplicacion, con el primer if valido para que el usuario intente calcular la multiplicacion sin poner nada, el segundo es que ponga un punto sin haber puesto un numero, y el tercero que haya puesto 0

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver con el enunciado. Debería ser algo así: "Validar que el usuario introduzca un decimal válido". Lo que no quiero es modificar la respuesta porque entonces no tendría nada que ver con la pregunta y futuros visitantes pueden confundirse.

Comment: Para mantener una organización te recomiendo que abras una nueva pregunta.

Comment: No puedo hacer mas preguntas:(

Comment: Por qué no puedes? Entonces edítala.

Comment: Me dice que debo esperar 3 dias, y ya edite el titulo, quizas si cambio el orden del 2 if funcionaria?

Comment: Hola, tambien pude resolverlo: en vez de validar.matches(".") puse validar.equals y funciono

Comment: El equals() no puede funcionar, porque este método lo que hace es verificar que dos Strings tienen el mismo contenido. Así que revísalo bien. Saludos.

Comment: Lo acabo de compilar en un dispositivo fisico y funciona al 100% con las 3 condiciones con equals. Puedes probarlo tu en tu android studio